# Owl Carousel not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Right, I'm working on a site for a friend, and I'm trying to get a carousel working. However, seemingly, no matter what I try.

Markup: http://pastebin.com/PjftpnJx

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

The Owl CSS files had their extension changed to .less and are included inside the main LESS file which I compile into CSS, which means that the files are there.

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: Only error I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:42
(anonymous function)`

Which seems odd considering I'm using jQuery

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Should be, considering the fact that in Chrome's dev tools I can click on the links, and other sites I've made uses a similar syntax.

Comment: the error means jquery is not loaded. use developer tool to check the jquery link and see if you get it

Comment: As said, it seemingly is linked. http://qs.lc/vextor/8ay.png

Clicking on it does redirect to the jQuery.min.js file.

Comment: do you have a live demo then? the markup looks so simple and I can't see where you could go wrong

Comment: I'll upload it to my server.

Comment: http://arrivance.mycpanel.co.uk/c

Comment: Seemingly, I had to link it to the server (e.g http:// link) for it to work.

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file that might be causing the issue?

Comment: I was testing this all locally, so I don't have a web server that could interfere with it.

Answer (score 7):

Found your problem, you won't believe how simple.
You just forgot to include the Owl Carousel stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
```

[**Working Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6d2cK/63/)

Edit: the problem is jQuery version, not working with 10.2, downgrade to 10.1 works.

Comment: Now that is odd, considering I included it within the LESS file that compiled into hhs2.css

http://qs.lc/vextor/9zl.png

Comment: that's odd, just tried your compiled css on fiddle and it still works

Comment: The error mainly seems to be jQuery not loading, but I can't figure out why it isn't loading.

Comment: version problem, try  using jquery 10.1

Comment: Seemingly, I had to link it to the server (e.g http:// link) for it to work.

I have no idea why this is

Comment: you need to change jquery version to 1.10.1, this carousel does not work with 1.10.2, you can play with my fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/6d2cK/1/. if you change jquery to 1.10.1 it works.

Comment: For me, the demos still don't work. Experiencing the same issue. Console is empty so no warnings or errors anywhere, still no carousel whatsoever...

Comment: @Sander that's because OWLGraphic deactivated their VPS and moved to a dedicated server. Now updated http://jsfiddle.net/6d2cK/63/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with OWL Carousel not working on IE and Chrome.

I've fixed it by replace the old version with the newest : http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/index.html

Now, Prev/Next buttons, Scroll-Drag and Auto-advance work on IE and Chrome.