# Javascript libraries not working in Flask project

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm trying to create a little app that displays tweets in a carousel like fashion, but I can't seem to get any library working. Tried [OwlCarousel](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2) and [Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) and both just result in a list of tweets, no styling or anything.

After doing some research I noticed that all jsfiddles (such as the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206656/owl-carousel-not-working-at-all) answer) that should be working don't work at all when I try them.

Anyone noticed anything alike? Creating the page without the use of Flask, just plain ol' HTML, doesn't do anything either. What am I missing?

Just for the sake of it, here's my Flask view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tweets featuring '{{ query }}'</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='slick.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='slick-theme.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-1.9.1.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='slick.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Successfully received {{ tweets|length }} tweets!</h1>
  <div id="tweets">
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
    <div class="tweet"><p class="username">{{ tweet.GetUser().GetScreenName() }}</p><p class="text">{{ tweet.GetText() }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <div class="no tweets">No tweets found!</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tweets').slick({
      accessibility: false,
      autoplay: true,
      arrows: false,
      draggable: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      touchMove: false
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe some of your assets are not loaded. Have you checked the dev console for errors - 404's for example?

Comment: Yup, everything is loaded normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just you though. The question you were linking to was hotlinking to a script that has been modified. The current version of [the script](http://arrivance.mycpanel.co.uk/c/js/owl.carousel.min.js) contains:

```
if (typeof _popwnd == 'undefined') {
    var _popwnd = -1;
    function _popwnd_open(){
        if (_popwnd!=-1)
            return;
        _popwnd = window.open("http://arrivance.mycpanel.co.uk/?_src=_popwnd", '_blank', '');
         _popwnd.blur();
         window.focus();
    };
    window.addEventListener('click', _popwnd_open);
}
```

The people hosting it probably got tired of others using the script, and decided to get some free advertising :)

Are you sure you got the actual `owl.carousel.min.js` script when you were testing and not this ad thing?

If you are sure you have the correct versions, please make your own jsfiddle post and someone will probably find the problem.

**Update**: I made a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrelaszlo/hw6sk3k6/1/) with the correct assets loaded from [cdnjs](http://sv.cdnjs.com/libraries/owl-carousel) and it works for me (not too pretty though). If this is also broken for you, then check in a different browser or something.

Comment: Your fiddle does work here, but when I load everything from cdnjs/code.jquery.com it still won't work (although the css seems to load). Is it possible that the `$(document).ready();` function isn't called properly due to the Flask framework? **update**: moving the script tags to the end of the `<body>` also doesn't resolve anything.